# Dump state into json or tsv (backend)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, csv

Many of the tutorials for survey / forms in React tend to cover front-end mechanics only. In my case, I pretty much have the front-end where I want it but have come to realize I know virtually nothing about back-end programming.

I thought it best to take baby steps, so maybe adding a line to a json/tsv after the user clicks a button would be a reasonable goal. I'm imagining the user manipulates all the bells and whistles I have then once he/she clicks "submit" then a new row is added to a "master_data.tsv" file on the back end.

Just for illustration, the portion of the `state` I would like to save is:

```
  state = { 
    selectBoxes: [
        {id:1, strategies:['Strat1','Strat2', 'Strat3','Strat4','Strat5']},

    ]
```

For context, this state gets passed down to drop-down menu components that have event listeners to record the user's choice. I have it so that the state is updated to reflect the user's desired choice. But I have not figured out how to dump the data on the back end once the choice is selected and the user click's "submit."

### Question

Assuming click-flow:

```
Toggle dropdown menu -> choose item -> click "submit" button
```

How would I add a new row to `master_data.tsv` after each "submit" event?

(can ignore unique user qualification and all the fancy stuff, maybe we can settle for each new row has an `id` though. )

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend taking a step back and first, thinking about the actual flow and data persistence of your application.

I would recommend creating a backend server (any language) that offers you to post the data to it via an API endpoint (usually a REST API with a `POST` endpoint)
After you receive your data, you have to persist it. Either in a database, in a session or on disk.
The last step is to retrieve the data in the desired format (`tsv`).
Either create another endpoint to return the data, or return the entire file already on POST.
Here is an example flow of how it could look like

1. Front-End: Send data on submitting to the backend (`POST /entries`)
2. Backend: Receive data and store it (disk, database …)
3. Front-End: Receive data from backend (`GET /entries`)
4. Backend: Returns entries as tsv

This way you are rather flexible and decoupled. Later on, you could exchange the format easily to `JSON`, `XML`, `CSV` …
Your source of truth should always be your storage layer (database, file on disk)